# Neural Network Plot Labels Being Cutoff

Tags: r, plot, neural-network

I am using the `neuralnet` package in R to build a visualization for predictor variables (X) and response variables (Y). I am only using this for visualization purposes and using Keras to actually build the NN as it seems to have better performance. Example data:

```
> nn_data
           X1         X2          X3         X4         X5         X6         X7          X8         X9        X10          Y1         Y2
1  -0.1565924 -1.0030593 -0.02056641 -1.7430156 -0.1579271 -0.2097874  1.8741489 -0.02649646 -0.6014566  2.2478350 -0.88938790  1.0729230
6   0.8073078  0.3294530  0.78198989  0.6650195 -0.1579271 -0.9358781 -0.5926292  0.89347504 -0.9376328 -0.3178219 -0.36057090 -0.5312203
11 -0.3008256  0.3294530 -0.23632296  0.1834125 -0.1579271 -0.9358781 -0.2693019  1.07332728 -0.7848254 -0.3178219 -0.01401961  0.4165173
14 -0.1378303  0.3294530 -0.65891339 -3.1878367 -0.1579271  0.5163032  3.1222146 -0.75026551  0.5306465 -0.3178219 -0.88938790  2.1685325
17 -0.1378303  0.3294530 -0.44164733  0.4242160 -0.1579271  0.5163032 -0.4805130 -0.75026551  0.5306465 -0.3178219 -0.19950344 -0.4497402
20 -0.1565924 -1.0030593 -0.49321695 -1.4219443 -0.1579271  0.5163032  1.4369397 -0.65434431  0.4739528 -0.3178219 -0.88938790  0.7551824
25 -0.1102736  0.3294530 -0.45000561  0.9058230 -0.1579271 -0.2097874 -0.8969763  0.87821485 -0.8109577 -0.3178219 -0.64410139 -0.8714469
31 -0.1999796 -1.0030593 -0.50669053 -1.1008729 -0.1579271  0.5163032  1.1871059 -0.65434431  0.4739528 -0.3178219  0.44637367  1.7805933
34 -0.1565924 -1.0030593 -0.74921508 -1.1811408 -0.1579271  0.5163032  1.2581717 -0.65434431  0.4739528 -0.3178219  0.48780091  1.8838869
41  0.9486095  0.8781346 -0.66042908  1.2268944 -0.1579271 -0.2097874 -1.1181190  0.32012787 -0.1744819 -0.3178219 -0.82560230 -0.8460502
```

I build the NN and set the `startweights` argument just so it completes faster. (Again, I'm just doing this for the visualization that is in the `neuralnet` package.)

```
targets <- c("Y1", "Y2")
n <- colnames(nn_data)
f <- as.formula(paste(paste(paste(targets, collapse= " + "), "~"), paste(n[!n %in% targets], collapse = " + ")))
net_model <- neuralnet(f, data=nn_data, hidden=c(8, 4, 4), stepmax=1e7, startweights= 1, linear.output=T)
```

However, when I plot it, the labels are always cut off:

```
plot(net_model)
```

[image]

I've tried adjusting the width and margins manually, but that doesn't seem to fix the issue.

```
# manually adjusting the width doesn't help
plot(net_model, width = 1500)
# setting the margins doesn't help
par(mar=c(2,2,2,2))
plot(net_model)
par(mai=c(.25, .25, .25, .25))
plot(net_model)
```

I've also tried various ways to save to a file; the files have the same image issue or they say there was an error in displaying the image. Is there a way to adjust the plot so that all the inputs/outputs are visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to get this to work with the `neuralnet` package, but was able to build an equivalent visualization with the `NeuralNetTools` package. I'm including it here in case somebody else needs to build a similar visualization:

The predictor (X) and response (Y) data:

```
> nn_data
            X1        X2         X3        X4 X5  X6         X7        X8         X9 X10         Y1        Y2
12 0.003408713 0.6777778 0.08750775 0.8415842  0 0.2 0.14894489 0.7029421 0.20006475 0.0 0.20704216 0.2546058
24 0.005570336 0.9444444 0.07693663 0.9405941  0 0.6 0.04510168 0.4804863 0.43293407 0.0 0.07850071 0.1560137
29 0.111157300 0.8666667 0.08750775 0.7029703  0 0.2 0.30075990 0.7029421 0.20006475 0.0 0.39500509 0.4075305
33 0.030428999 0.7777778 0.15659785 0.8910891  0 0.2 0.08771594 0.6781747 0.16283587 0.0 0.08929058 0.1587997
37 0.022780180 0.5666667 0.18330628 0.7623762  0 0.2 0.23507544 0.7029421 0.20006475 0.0 0.00000000 0.2216897
40 0.004073828 1.0000000 0.23713206 0.9801980  0 0.8 0.02099278 0.3902232 0.55789360 0.5 0.08631579 0.1652908
43 0.003408713 0.8666667 0.10497009 0.8910891  0 0.2 0.08782528 0.6781747 0.16283587 0.0 0.12705535 0.1678637
46 0.026521450 0.9444444 0.13545964 0.8217822  0 0.6 0.14935491 0.4518163 0.52055681 0.0 0.48400642 0.2122799
47 0.019371467 0.9444444 0.09350644 0.8712871  0 0.2 0.06904658 0.9500901 0.08972699 0.5 0.11964409 0.1798325
48 0.007316262 0.6777778 0.01894009 0.5148515  0 0.2 0.48332604 0.7029421 0.20006475 0.0 0.51161613 0.5699047

library(NeuralNetTools)
targets <- c("Y1", "Y2")
n <- colnames(nn_data)
n_output <- length(targets)
n_input <- ncol(nn_data) - n_output
# define the NN structure
struct <- c(n_input, 8, 4, 4, n_output) #ten inputs, three hidden layers, two output 

# we need to count how many weights there are based on the nodes/biases
n_weights <- 0
for(i in 1:length(struct))
{
  if(i == 1)
  {
    # n_inputs * n_nodes of first hidden layer
    n_weights <- n_weights + struct[i] * struct[i + 1]
  }else if(i < length(struct))
  {
    # hidden layer node count + bias count
    n_weights <- n_weights + (struct[i] * struct[i+1]) + struct[i]
  } else {
    # output bias count
    n_weights <- n_weights + struct[i] 
  }
}

# build the visual (again with all weight = 1 bc I just want the visual)
wts_in <- rep(1, times=n_weights) 
x_names <- n[!n %in% targets]
y_names <- targets
plotnet(wts_in, struct = struct, x_names = x_names, y_names = y_names)
```

The visual is created by `plotnet()` but I don't have enough SO reputation points to include in this answer.